# How to stop Text timer in ios swiftUI widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, dynamic-island, widgetliveactivity

I have a live activity and dynamic island widget with text component timer.
Widget is using ActivityConfiguration and how can i stop the timer or close the widget once it reaches specified date?

This is how the timer is implemented

```
ActivityConfiguration(for: ExtensionAttributes.self) { context in
    Text(context.attributes.date, style: .timer)
}
```

And when the date reaches date + 2 hours, i need to stop this timer or remove the widget.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can display a timer in the live activity by using the Text initialiser that takes in a date range like so;

```
struct TimerAttributes: ActivityAttributes {
public typealias TimerStatus = ContentState

public struct ContentState: Codable, Hashable {
    var startDate: Date
}

var timeRange: ClosedRange<Date>
var timerName: String
```

}

```
struct TimerActivityView : View {
let context: ActivityViewContext<TimerAttributes>

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Text(timerInterval: context.attributes.timeRange,
                 countsDown: false)
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can i perform some actions once the text reaches the range, like replacing timer counter with "Completed" text